# How to drop output package buffers in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, buffer, ppp

I have a linux embedded system running kernel 3.8 (BBB). The network layers are like this:

- application (uses UDP/IP and ICMP/IP protocol)
- pppd over a serial tty
- usbserial
- an usb hardware which provides a transparent radio transmitter/receiver via serial-over-usb port (slow link, 19kbps)

When there are problems with the radio-link (or maybe with the usb-hardware), packages are not send (so they are buffered at some place -- maybe at the ppp or at the kernel).

However, since the environment is noisy, the link gets down/up many times per hour.

The packages are being buffered at some place, because when the link establishes, all buffered packages get send (overloading temporarely the low-speed link).

I've seen some rare cases where I got an ICMP-echo-reply with RTT of 400 seconds! (even more than the max TTL allowed of 255 seconds or hops)

My Questions:

- how to know if these packages are being buffered by the kernel, by pppd, or by usbserial?
- how to tell (manually) the (kernel or pppd or usbserial) to discard output buffers?
- how can I check (or limit) how much memory is being used by these buffers?

Comment: Hi pzn. Have you solved the issue above?